# Paste text from clipboard in different fonts Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am using some other fonts then default from android.

I am using [this fonts](http://www.1001freefonts.com/montague.font)

I am copying this font in clip board using this code

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",txtGhost.getText().toString());
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Now i have paste and i am getting same text but not the same font. 
My Question is how i can paste same text and same font style that i have picked in my android application.

Comment: for now i am pasting in textview inside app . but i want to paste it outside as well. anywhere.